# Adding a WHERE statement testing the geometry type of a feature to a PostGIS query makes it very long to execute

Tags: postgis

I have a PostGIS query which should return records containing 3D geometries as `ST_LineString`. Those geometries are the result of a 3D intersection between a defined 3D triangle A and a table containing 10 millions of other 3D triangles.

99.999% of those are actually `ST_LineString`. It's mathematically expected.

But some rare results have a geometry type `ST_GeometryCollection`.

When trying to unpack those specific records using `ST_AsText(ST_CollectionExtract(line_feature,X))` (with X = {1,2,3} for respectively points, lines and polygons features), it shows, for every X, empty geometries. I'm surprised:

[image]
*The "does_intersect" column is the result of `ST_3Dintersects()` function.*

Notice that I do test all intersections using `ST_3DIntersects` prior to actually *computing* the geometrical intersections using `ST_3DIntersection` and every single response is `true`, even those rare results showing empty geometry collections.

This sounds like a bug and I will try to build a small reproducible example (because for the moment, the SQL query itself is quite large and depends on specific data).

But the most interesting part is that I want to filter out those geometry collections using a `WHERE` statement, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM
(
    SELECT
    *,
    ST_GeometryType(geom) AS geom_type
    FROM <large subquery>
)
WHERE geom_type ILIKE 'st_linestring`;
```

The original query, without the `WHERE` statement is taking roughly 2 minutes to execute and it results in 2'500 records.
While it has now been for more than 1h30 that it's running with the `WHERE` statement...

Does anybody know what's wrong with such textual comparison on the geometry type?

I was thinking it's maybe an index issue, but I cannot build an index on geometries which are actually computed by a running query, can I?

#### EDIT:

When trying to run `EXPLAIN` in front of my query it say:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXPLAIN"
LINE 1: ... false, BUFFERS false, SUMMARY true, SETTINGS true) EXPLAIN 
                                                               ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 122
```

but by using the button from the pgAdmin4 GUI I got a single node:

1. without the `WHERE` statement:

```
Index Scan using triangles_table_idx on public.triangles_table as t 
(cost=0.42..36987599.13 rows=713167 width=217)

    Filter: st_3dintersects('010F0000A...A8E40'::geometry, t.triangle)
    
    Index Cond: (t.triangle && '010F0000A...A8E40'::geometry)
```

2. with the `WHERE` statement:

```
Index Scan using triangles_table_idx on public.triangles_table as t 
(cost=0.42..18984157.09 rows=3566 width=217)

    Filter: ((st_geometrytype(st_3dintersection('010F0000A...9C99A8E40'::geometry, t.triangle)) = 'ST_LineString'::text)
            AND st_3dintersects('010F0000A...A8E40'::geometry, t.triangle))
    
    Index Cond: (t.triangle && '010F0000A...A8E40'::geometry)
```

```
PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu,
    compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit

POSTGIS="3.1.4 ded6c34"
    [EXTENSION]
        PGSQL="140"
        GEOS="3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2"
        SFCGAL="1.3.8"
        PROJ="7.2.1"
        LIBXML="2.9.10"
        LIBJSON="0.15"
        LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3"
        WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"
        TOPOLOGY
```

Comment: There should be no need to use ILIKE but probably `WHERE geom_type='ST_LineString';` is not any faster.

Comment: Indeed, but still a huge difference in the execution time with the standard query (i.e. without the `WHERE` statement).

Comment: Also, you already know what the geometry type is because you use it as a filter in WHERE so instead of `ST_GeometryType(geom) AS geom_type FROM <large subquery>` you could try `'ST_LineString' AS geom_type`.

Comment: what does the query plan says?

Comment: @JGH : Updated. But I'm not able to properly interpret the `EXPLAIN` results.

Comment: without the `where`, it says it returns 713167 rows... much more than the 2500 you have mentioned, so there must be something else filtering (or not, in the 2nd case) the results. You can try preventing the planner from "moving" the geom_type check to the inner query by adding `OFFSET 0` after the `<large subquery>`

Comment: Okay, the `OFFSET 0` definitely did the job. It also made 1 additional node (i.e. line) show up in the `EXPLAIN` results! This is definitely black magic to me; a technical explanation would be more than welcome.

Comment: The issue here is *predicate pushdown* - the query planner reorders your filter conditions and flattens the sub-query structure. It usually does that rightfully, but with more complexity it may not be able to determine the most performant sequence. A more in-depth analysis would require knowing that sub-query you run. The `OFFSET` acts as a fence for the planner - it is not allowed to flatten the query. You could get the same result with a mazerialized CTE.

Comment: As to why the `OFFSET` acts as a fence here; consider that, in order for the planner to retrieve resulting rows at a given offset, it needs to know (i.e. produce) the full result set first, so the given sub-query needs to get fully executed first.

Comment: here is an old [blog](http://web.archive.org/web/20210414165005/https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2009/04/07/offset-0-ftw) on this topic, and a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47680671/explain-postgres-query-why-is-the-query-that-much-longer-with-where-and-limit) on PG's inability to get cross-table correlations